# Recyclerview populate with json

Tags: android, json, rest, api, deserialization

I want to fetch json data from url to show it on User Interface. But failed to deserialize the data in correct order. I use Retrofit 1.9. The problem is when I run this code withot any image deserialize funtionality , for example title, body, updateDate that time it is working fine. I can see the recyclerview with heading and date. but when I try to run with follwoing code, the recyclerview getting blank. I can see nothing on that. I am trying hard to identify. Bu nothing could solve my problem. It would be really helpful for me if someone help me to identify the problem.

The Controller Class

```
public class NewsController {
private static final String TAG = NewsController.class.getSimpleName();
private UserCallbackListener mListener;
private NewsRestApiManager mApiManager;

public NewsController(UserCallbackListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mApiManager = new NewsRestApiManager();
}

public void startFetching(){

    mApiManager.getNewsApi().getNews(new Callback<String>() {

        @Override
        public void success(String s, Response response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "JSON :: " + s);

            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);

                for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    NewsModel news = new NewsModel();
                    news.setTitle( object.optString( "title") );
                    news.setBody( object.optString( "body" ) );

                   /* if I comment downd this postion the app run perfectly but except image*/
                    ArrayList<AppImage> list = new ArrayList();
                    JSONArray imageArray =object.getJSONArray("appImages");
                    for(int j=0; j<imageArray.length();j++){
                        AppImage appImages  = new AppImage();
                        appImages.setSrc(imageArray.getJSONObject( j ).getString( "src" ));
                        list.add(appImages);
                    }
                    news.setAppImages( list );

                // I want to set this image ad Heading Image
                    JSONObject jo=object.getJSONObject( "teaserImageSmall​" );
                    TeaserImageSmall coverImage=new TeaserImageSmall();
                    coverImage.setSrc( jo.optString( "src" ));
                    news.setTeaserImageSmall(coverImage);
                    mListener.onFetchProgress(news);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                mListener.onFetchFailed();
            }


            mListener.onFetchComplete();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error :: " + error.getMessage());
            mListener.onFetchComplete();
        }
    });

}
public interface UserCallbackListener{
    void onFetchStart();
    void onFetchProgress(NewsModel news);
    void onFetchProgress(List<NewsModel> userList);
    void onFetchComplete();
    void onFetchFailed();
}
```

}

My adapter class is

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NewsHolder holder, int position) {
    final NewsModel currentNews = mNews.get(position);
    Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext());
    Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(currentNews.getTeaserImageSmall().getSrc()).into( holder.newsImage );

    holder.newsHeadline.setText(currentNews.getTitle());
    holder.newsDate.setText(currentNews.getPostDate());
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i=new Intent(context,DetailNews.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            //i.putExtra("image",newsModel.getImage());
            i.putExtra("title",currentNews.getTitle());
            i.putExtra("body",currentNews.getBody());
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
appImages.setSrc(imageArray.optString(("src")));
```

Do not use Integer.parseInt here, Since you have a String data in src.
Add this list to `NewsModel.appImages=list;` outside iteration of this images array.

Now In Adapter class,

```
 holder.newsImage.appImage.get(position).getSrc();
```

Hope this works :)

Comment: How can I get source of TeaserImageSmall

Comment: I am not sure about the implementtaion JSONARRAY jsonarray=object.optString("appImages");. Because I already define json array. Shall I do it twice. Could you plaese explain more based on my code

Comment: Sure..
There's no need for TeaserImageSmall.
you have to define another json array because in your json "appImages" is having a json array data so response will give you an array which you have to iterate. You can refer parsing of nested json data that will help you more.

Comment: Code provided above is already based on your code..I'll clear it more in couple of minutes..

Comment: I need to fetch the src from teaserImageSmall. Because it is the cover image. But I  was not able to fethch it from json. I just modified my code in question

Comment: I am gettimg error for this line appImages.setSrc(imageArray.optString(("src"))); showing optString(int) in JsonArray cannot be applied. also where Can I set NewsModel.appImages=list; your naming in code is different from my code, that is wahy I am getting confused

Comment: @user88152604 Could you plaese also explain how can I get "src": "http://HeadlineIMage.JPG" from testImage class. Because I want to show this image as cover Image on news.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NewsModel.AppImages appImages = new NewsModel.AppImages(); 
 appImages.setSrc(imageArray.optString(("src")));
```

Do not use Integer.parseInt here, Since you have a String data in src.
Add this list to

```
 NewsModel.appImages=list;
```

outside iteration of this images array.

```
 JSONOBJECT Jo= object.getJsonObject("teaserImageSmall​");
 NewsModel.teaserImageSmall= Jo.optString("src");
```

Now In Adapter class,

```
 holder.newsImage.setImage(mNews.appImage.get(position).getSrc());
 String cover= mNews.teaserImageSmall;
```

Hope this works :)

Comment: you code is not working. I still cant undersdand your code

Comment: Buddy, This should parse the above json provided by you. May be minor typing error is here..but code is correct.
It is basic json parsing

Comment: I have edited my question.  I have created seperate class for appimage and teaserImageSample. Now if I run my code without image array portion  it is working. that time only title and date is showing in recyclerview. but if I want to run it with image url code, the reycclerview become blank. if you need my model class then I can also provide that in this code. I do not understand what would be the problem in controller class.